# How do you make Google Test honour static local variables?

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I am using Google Test (against my better judgement) to unit-test a C programme. A particular function uses a static local variable (because of the principle of minimal scope) to flip-flop between two buffers (or to iterate through as many as you like), from which the function receives data.

My build system is CMake 3.21.0

The basic structure is:

```c
process_result_t
myFunction(void)
{
  static uint32_t  last_buffer_idx = 0u;
  uint32_t         buffer_idx      = 0u;
  uint32_t         ii              = 0u;
  process_result_t process_result  = OK;

  last_buffer_idx++;

  for (ii = 0u; ii < BUFFER_QUANTITY; ii++)
  {
    buffer_idx = (last_buffer_idx + ii) % BUFFER_QUANTITY;
    process_result = processBuffer(buffer_idx);

    if (NO_DATA == process_result)
    {
      last_buffer_idx = buffer_idx;
      break;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This is a sort of load-balancing, whereby each call of the function finds the next buffer with data in it, and processes that data, then returns `OK`, or `OTHERERROR` if there's a problem. If none of the buffers has data waiting - and only if *none* has data waiting - then the function returns `NO DATA`.

I build the unit test script and then run `make test`; the tests fail. I run the binary directly, because this gives more information about failing tests; the tests succeed.

Why? Because when running the tests via `make test`, the static local variable `last_buffer_idx` is reset before each test. It appears there is some black magic at work whereby each test is run as a separate instance of the binary. I have checked this by changing the expected buffer numbers in each failing test.

How can I force GoogleTest, or CMake, or whatever it is, to run all the tests together?

Comment: Am I right in understanding that your tests depend on the order in which they are run, each test building on the results of the previous test?  That is going to be problematic, I think.  You'll probably have to make the sequence of tests into a single GoogleTest test.

Comment: You should consider refactoring your code and making it re-entrant instead, storing state in a local variable passed as a pointer as an argument.

Comment: Once again an example why the Singleton pattern (here: the static variable) is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Oh, and what do you mean with the difference between running with `make test` and running the binary? We are using GoogleTest, too, and each test suite is a single binary.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
1. The tests depend on the order if the binary is run directly. This is really the intended behaviour and part of what is being tested. Nonetheless, it is not a single test.
2. Yes, adding in a state variable is the best alternative, but I am reticent to do this, because it doesn't *need* to be passed.
3. Thank you. I'm inclined to think GoogleTest is causing this issue.
4. I'm new to GoogleTest, so maybe there are options, but only one binary is produced for me per unit under test.